# filter and send a contact database

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I have a script that sends emails to a contact list. I would like to filter the large list each time I send and wondered what would be the best way to store the temporary list?

I was thinking of creating a temporary table which contained the filtered results and then dropping it at the end of the script. Is there an easier way to store the results?

The contact list is in the the thousands.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the use of a temporary table, but would also suggest independent views.

If you frequently filter your tables and need to create many temporary tables, why not create multiple views, which would contain results only for the criteria you wish, and sending mail based on that.

This would prevent the need for creating and dropping tables, but would only benefit you if you use the same filter many times.

Comment: Ah yeah that's a great idea, so create the desired view with its own SQL statement and then when happy, dump it into a table?

Comment: Don't even need to go that far. Make a SELECT statement until you get all the desired rows. When you have your select statement, do, `CREATE VIEW filter_a AS ` then put your select statement here. Then in the future any changes to your original contacts table will automatically reflect in the view, without needing to recreate it.

Comment: Thats fantastic, I didn't realise that existed in SQL! Maybe a bit of reading and trial and error on my part but thanks so much for your suggestion!

Comment: Take a look at `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html`. Also, if you need to get the command used to create a view, use `show create view viewname` where viewname is the name of your view.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary table would work fine.  Unless you have extremely lacking hardware, or are doing numerous complex joins, thousands of records is nothing for MySQL.